# Not Understanding ? Why do we need BLOB in "Android Sqlite"

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I am not understanding why do we need BLOB in SQlite. I have seen this explanation in some of the documents

BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

But I did not get what it is ? and why is it necessary ? Please provide me some suggestions.

Regards
Anand

Comment: If you don't know what it's used for, don't use it. If you don't understand what it's used for, just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

BLOB is an acronym that means

**B** inary **L** arge **OB** ject

So, it's a container for stuff that you want stored "as such" without the need to serialize them to eg a clean string, and that are typically larger than the usual types that are stored in a database.  Examples are serialized objects (a serialized object is represented by a stream of bytes), bitmaps, sound clips, etc.

Answer (score -1):

when need store ordinary object in database like ImageView at that time 
blob type use for that